# JMeter HTML report - HTTP requests named <name>-0, <name>-1 <name>-2 etc - Why?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have two thread groups in my project, and on of them has two HTTP request samplers. It's set up like the following

Thread group
   **Timer**: Random between 1 and 5 minutes: ${__Random(60000,300000)}
   **HTTP request**: A basic GET web service call
   **HTTP request**: A basic GET web service call

Here's the Thread group setup.

[image]

That's it. Here's an example of the web service call setup

[image: HTTP Request]

And here's what the "Statistics" portion of the HTML report looks like. Note the -1, -2 after the HTTP Request names. I'm trying to figure out why that's happening.

[image: Statistics]

My other thread group / samplers are not displaying that way, but they're set up the same way, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, **HTTP requests Get Locations-0, Get Locations-1** are sub requests of Get Locations which appeared since you have selected the check box - Follow Redirects.
[image]

In case, you don't want **HTTP requests Get Locations-0, Get Locations-1** to appear in your HTML report:
In the listener page(where you have saved the result file; which is the source file of HTML report) -> click on configure button -> uncheck the Save Sub Result option

[image]

You can also refer :[Configure result file to customize HTML report](https://youtu.be/NCBPpKcLhiA?list=PLkkGqdBS1r094KcNXRy4Q-v5biuNWv-h7&t=942)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that some of the calls were returning a 200, others a 301, that's where they got separated out, even though the 301's didn't register as errors in the report.